# Pandas iloc returns cell index instead of value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel file with multiple sheets, each one contains data in different start and end rows. I was able to come up with the code below but it returns the cell index instead of value:

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

data_range = [{"Sheet": "Sheet1", "Start": 21, "End": 25}, {"Sheet": "Sheet2", "Start": 20, "End": 26}, {"Sheet": "Sheet3", "Start": 21, "End": 24}] # start and end index for each sheet

book = openpyxl.load_workbook(PATH_TO_FILE) # actual data
for sh in book.sheetnames:
    for d in data_range:
        if d['Sheet'] == sh:
            i = data_range.index(d)
            start = data_range[i]['Start']
            end = data_range[i]['End']
            range_output = pd.DataFrame(book[sh]).iloc[start:end]
            print(range_output)
```

The output looks like this:

```
                  0                1                2                3
21  <Cell 'Sheet1'.A22>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.B22>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.C22>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.D22>   
22  <Cell 'Sheet1'.A23>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.B23>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.C23>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.D23>   
23  <Cell 'Sheet1'.A24>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.B24>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.C24>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.D24>   
24  <Cell 'Sheet1'.A25>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.B25>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.C25>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.D25>   
25  <Cell 'Sheet1'.A26>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.B26>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.C26>  <Cell 'Sheet1'.D26>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You can read excel sheets using pandas too, and simply specify the range of values you want to read from it.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get that with Pandas.